# Python kivy сборка apk пакетов

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

Пишу мобильное приложение на python kivy и собираю в линукс с помощью buildozer. Подскажите пожалуйста, как задать картинку приложения, отображаемую в меню на андроид? Может стоит поколдовать с `buildozer.spec`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, как и думал все находится в файле buildozer.spec.

```
# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png
```

Вот тут указываете путь к иконке.

P.S
Надеюсь помог кому-нибудь